# Media transfer protocol node js

Tags: android, node.js

I am looking for a way to transfer files from a windows machine to an android device using node js using the media transfer protocol, or any other way if possible as i would like to move some files listed on the computer to the device. I would also guess i could run an executable in a child process, but have no experience in writing an executable that could be run. Any help or resources to accomplish this I would be very grateful. There is also no guarantee of being able to mount the device which is why i thought MTP.